# SQL Case Query with n-to-m relationship

Tags: sql, informix

I have a 500 line SQL query I'm working on so I'll try to use a simpler example....

Assume I have a table `Books` that has `Book_id`, `Author` and `Title` columns, a table `Publisher` that has publisher information and a table `Translations` that contains `Book_id`, `Title` and `Language` columns.

I want to `SELECT` all books from a certain publisher regardless of whether or not they've been translated into Spanish, but I do want to show a column that contains `true` if they have a Spanish translation.

So assume that my query is `SELECT Author, Title, Spanish FROM Books, Translations WHERE Publisher.Book_id = Books.Book_id AND Translations.Book_id = Books.Book_id AND Publisher_id = 1`. How do I get a true in the Spanish column from a table that can contain the same book several times or no times ?

Comment: You select from Books and Translations, but you specify conditions on Publisher too.  You're missing a table from the FROM clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax!  I do hope that you don't have 500 lines of code using commas for joins.

You want a `left join` and `case` expression:

```
SELECT b.Author, b.Title, 
       (CASE WHEN t.Book_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as spanish_flag
FROM Books b LEFT JOIN
     Translations t
     ON t.Book_id = b.Book_id AND
        t.language = 'Spanish'  
WHERE b.Publisher_id = 1;
```

Note:  This uses a string representation for `'true'`/`'false'`.  You haven't specified the database.  Some have direct support for booleans.

Actually, a suppose a book could have multiple translations into a single language.  A more natural way to write the query uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.Author, b.Title, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM Translations t
                          WHERE t.Book_id = b.Book_id AND
                                t.language = 'Spanish'
                         ) 
             THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
        END) as spanish_flag
FROM Books b
WHERE b.Publisher_id = 1;
```

Comment: Database is Informix, I assumed that most people don't really know the specific syntax. Also actually yes, there are some "outer" joins but most of it is just where x.id = y.id. This is in a file of 17,500 lines of VB code (it's been growing for a while)

Comment: I was waiting for other answers (and to test if this works/does what I want) and then I forgot to accept. Works well (with slight tweaks (removed "as" keyword). Thank you.